# Rails: Resize image that is linked from another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resize, image-resizing

Until now, I have used this:

```
<%= image_tag("thumb.png", size: "180x95") %>
```

and it the image got resized.

Now I want to change to this:

`<%= image_tag(p.thumbnail, size: "180x95") %>` (where p.thumbnail is http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/272/361/272361059_200.jpg)

The problem is that the picture won't resize with the new code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so I found the solution. You will have to set the height and width in CSS for it to work. I don't know why, but it works :)

View file:

```
<%= image_tag(p.thumbnail, class: "hoi") %>
```

CSS:

```
.hoi{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
}
```